# Incorrect path url for a jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple question. I would like to proceed  to a jquery $.ajax request. I have some trouble with the 'url' right formatting. My index.php is in some folder, call it 'public'. In this folder, I have also my js files. Sharing the same level of the tree than 'public', I have a folder called 'classes' where I put my php files. I want to make an ajax request from an html page which is in the publuc folder. So for the 'url' data of the jquery ajax method, I put '../classes/ajax.php'

But it didn't work. Do I have a path syntax problem?

Comment: Structure in the folder /mysite, you have two folders /classes and /public.  In /public : ndex.php, /html_folder, /js_folder and in /classes : php files

Comment: Please add your folder structure to your original question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The path is relative to the current url (as displayed in the browser address bar), so you need to consider the path to the destination relative to the page that is currently loaded.

Either that or use a url beginning with "/..." to start form the site root.

The path to the script file (which is executing the ajax) is irrelevant.

This does mean that if you need to access the same ajax url from pages which are in different levels of the directory tree, you need to reference the path using an absolute url.

```
\Pages
    \Section1
        MyPage1.html
    \Section2.html
        MyPage2.html
\Scripts
    MyScript.js
\Ajax
    MyService.php
```

If calling the ajax service from MyPage1.html, the path would be `../../Ajax/MyService.html` or an absolute path `/Ajax/MyService.html`